# Incrementing keys for a multi-user tool in google cloud datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-datastore

I am building a tool using the Google Cloud Datastore Java API. The backend of this tool has a bunch of methods and APIs that we made which are hosted on the Google App Engine. The data we collect from the tool comes from a Chrome extension we built and using the above mentioned APIs we store our data in GCD. Everything works perfectly well in our implementation except for one thing, the Identifiers.

I created a method to store all our relevant information in several tables and while submitting I am creating each Entity with an Identifier which is the next number in ascending order from the previous entry in the table. The tool is being used by several people and the entries for that particular day are stored in correct order. However, everyday it seems that thee ID variable is reset and our table starts overwriting information as the ID starts from 1 again. It remains constant during that day but soon as the date changes, the ID starts from 1 again.

```
AtomicInteger Identifier = new AtomicInteger();
public void DataEntity(String EmpName, String Date, String Col1, String Col2)
    {
        id = Identifier.incrementAndGet();
        Entity en = new Entity("DataTable", id);
        task.setProperty("Employee Name", EmpName);
        task.setProperty("Submit_Date", Date);
        task.setProperty("Column1", Col1);
        task.setProperty("Column2", Col2);
        ...
        ds.put(en);
    }
```

My guess is that at the end of the day all the methods are garbage collected. I should also note that our app is threadsafe, hence, data is not getting overwritten simultaneously. Only the next day when all the variables seem to have been reset and everything starts from 1. Any help will be much appreciated. Please let me know in case you have any questions. I'll be happy to provide more info.

Comment: What is the implementation of `AtomicInteger`?  If it is stored in memory, (i) it will lose its value as soon as the instance shuts down, (ii) each instance will have its own count. There are many ways to design a counter for Datastore (e.g., [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters)). (Also, Java conventions suggest your `Identifier` and `DataEntity()` should start with a *lowerCase* letter).

Comment: @tx802: Thanks. I will try this out. That's the thing that has me a bit baffled actually. Even if I shut down the instance and open a new one an hour or two later, the count continues. It stays the same way the whole day(for that date). But soon as the date changes and a new instance is instantiated, the counter seems to get reset to 1 and it starts overwriting my data.

Comment: Sorry, I missed to answer one question. The AtomicInteger is stored in App Engine where the code is hosted. And also, I changed some names right before I posted them here so messed up in a hurry.